# What is an algorithm to prove that a transliteration scheme is lossless?

Tags: string, algorithm, sequence, lossless, data-transform

Say you want to convert one set of characters to another. Instead of there being a 1-1 mapping of each character in set A to a corresponding character in set B, it's slightly more complicated. Think of like a natural language transliterator from a script like [Thai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_11940) or [Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKATS) to Latin script. In the Korean example, you get something like this:

```
SKATS:  LUM CU LE  MEG KUGG BE.
Hangul: 김치가 맛있다.
```

There is a 1-to-1 mapping of SKATS to Korean Hangul. `LU` is one letter, `M` another, `CU` another, etc. There is no correspondence between these letters and the pronunciation of the Hangul characters, these are just picked from a hat basically.

The issue starts to come in when you have multiple characters represent a single character.

Say for example you have an "aspirated `t`" sound, represented as `tʰ` in [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), and you also have the letters `t` and `h`, and you have the english `th` sound (`θ` in IPA). Say you decide to represent the `tʰ` sound as `th`. Well, you  could have this actual sequence:

```
tʰ-tʰ-th-t-t-h-t-tʰ-h-th
```

If you translated that it would be:

```
 th-th-th-t-t-h-t-th-h-th
```

Combined how it would actually look is:

```
 thththtthtthhth
```

Now the problem is how to get back to the original character sequence. We could interpret this in many ways:

```
 th-th-th-t-th-t-th-h-th
 th-th-th-t-t-h-t-th-h-th
 th-th-th-t-t-h-t-t-h-h-th
 th-th-th-t-t-h-t-t-h-h-t-h
 th-th-th-t-t-h-t-t-h-h-tʰ
 th-th-th-t-t-h-t-tʰ-h-tʰ
 etc.
```

How do you write an algorithm that will check if your mapping is 1:1 lossless to prevent this problem? I am trying to wrap my head around it for a few days but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Another example is if you have "single letters" be transcoded into "ts", "s", "t", "h", "th", "tsh", "thsh", etc. So then you have a real problem.

Comment: I think the problem here is that, even if many interpretations for original sequence exist, it does not necessarily mean that we cannot use it. for example this: `th-th-th-t-th-t-th-h-th` can be semantically meaningful, while this: `th-th-th-t-t-h-t-th-h-th` is not, so we still can use the 1st interpretation. Only if there are 2 or more semantically meaningful and semantically different interpretations for the same sequence, means that we cannot use a given encoding

Comment: The property you're looking for is a *uniquely decodable code*, with a *prefix-free code* being the simplest way to achieve it.  The [Sardinas–Patterson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas–Patterson_algorithm) can determine if other codes are uniquely decodable.

Comment: I just realize that I incorrectly understood Post correspondence problem. Please ignore my previous comment.